# How to constrain polyfit coef. to a certain precision (matlab)?

Tags: matlab

I wish to fit a polynomial curve (4 ou 5 degree) to my data. I did it with EXCEL and I get coefficient around 10^-13 for the 5th one, 10^-9 for the 4th one and 10^-5 for the third one...
I would like to constrain all the coefficients to not be lower than 10^-2. The curve won't be fitted that good but it is ok.
How can I do that with the `polyfit` function ?

And then, from a mathematical point of vue. Does it make sense to constrain coefficient ? Or is it useless and I better keep going with a second degree polyfit (which has coefficient lower than 10^-2).

The reason I'm asking this : I'm doing some research and from a physical point of view, it is interesting to test the 5th degree polyfit but I can't use coefficient lower than 10^-2.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this with `polyfit` since that function returns the coefficients that minimizes the error (I think in the 2-norm) between the polynomial and the data.  It is what it is.  Is the data you have supposed to be follow fifth order polynomial or this is a brute-force curve fit?

Comment: The size of coefficients depends on the units you use on the horizontal axis. If you have x-values in the thousands, the higher degree coefficients will have to be extremely small, of the results will be off the chart. Consider rescaling the variable.

Comment: I can't rescale because I will use the coefficient in another prog that will use the initial horizontal scale. My data are supposed to follow a fifth order polynomial (R^2 =0.95).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fit` rather than `polyfit`

```
%What is the degree of the polynomial (quartic)
polyDegree = 4;

%This sets up the options
opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'LinearLeastSquares' );

%All coefficients of degrees not specified between x^n and x^0 can have any value greater than 10^-2
opts.Lower = 1E-2;
opts.Upper = inf(1, polyDegree + 1);

%Do the fit using the specified polynomial degree.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( x, y, ['poly', num2str(polyDegree)] , opts );
```